# RichFaces4 startup fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: class javax.faces.convert.DoubleConverter

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

This seems not be not a simple task with RichFaces4 without Maven, I download myfaces-2.0.9 jars and richfaces 4.0.0 and added sac-1.3.jar, guava-r08.jar and cssparser-0.9.5.jar.

The environment I am working is Tomcat 6.0, But I am unable to setup a simple richfaces4 based web application when ever I run tomcat I get different issues. I added few jars related to the below error but I get another duplicate key error for another converter,

On an other note: I also had to remove tomohawk from tomcat as I was using myfaces. Please help.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: class javax.faces.convert.DoubleConverter
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:72)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.fromEntryList(ImmutableMap.java:221)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:207)
    at org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parseConfig(ClientServiceConfigParser.java:54)
    at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.createClientScriptService(ValidatorModule.java:68)
    at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.configure(ValidatorModule.java:62)
    at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.init(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:28)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.createFactory(InitializationListener.java:136)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStart(InitializationListener.java:110)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:152)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2334)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:554)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:254)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 6, 2011 7:13:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 6, 2011 7:13:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/testRichFaces4] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 6, 2011 7:13:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.application.CacheProvider.release(CacheProvider.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.release(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:19)
    at org.richfaces.application.ServiceTracker.release(ServiceTracker.java:100)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStop(InitializationListener.java:144)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:154)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2334)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:554)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:254)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.destroyFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4846)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 6, 2011 7:13:29 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4846)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen if you also include the RichFaces **source code** JAR files in the classpath. They do not belong in the webapp's runtime classpath. It are the ones with a filename ending in `-source.jar`. You should **remove** them from the `/WEB-INF/lib` and put them if necessary somewhere else which do not end up in the webapp's runtime classpath.

The culprit is the `csv.xml` file which is present in `/META-INF` folder of both the `richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar` and `richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final-source.jar` files. That file definies the standard converters and validators. However, because that file now appears twice in the classpath, it's been read twice, resulting in this duplicate key exception.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, removing Tomahawk because you're using MyFaces is a non-argument. The MyFaces JSF implementation does not contain the same components as Tomahawk. It's just another JSF implementation and technically the competitor of Mojarra. Tomahawk is a standalone component library which offers more enhanced components on top of the standard JSF implementation and can be used as good on top of every JSF implementation.

Comment: @BalusC,  Genius!!