# IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key (JSF)

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces

I'm using Tomcat 7, Richfaces 4.2.2, MyFaces 2.1.5 and Facelets. When I start Tomcat I get the error:

```
An error occured while initializing MyFaces: duplicate key: class javax.faces.convert.BooleanConverter

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: class javax.faces.convert.BooleanConverter
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:72) 
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.fromEntryList(ImmutableMap.java:221)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:207)
at org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parseConfig(ClientServiceConfigParser.java:53)
at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.createClientScriptService(ValidatorModule.java:65)
at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.configure(ValidatorModule.java:60)
at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.init(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:27)
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.createFactory(InitializationListener.java:139)
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStart(InitializationListener.java:112)
at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:157)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2105)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:118)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2292)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:537)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:248)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I saw the solution presented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681582/richfaces4-startup-fails-with-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-duplicate-key), but different in this case, I don't have "-source.jar" in my classpath.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm was the same boat as you are.

Taking off from the post you've linked to, I inspected all of my JAR files in WEB-INF/lib and found that both `richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar` and `richfaces-ui-validator-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar` contain a file `META-INF/csv.xml` which provides a mapping for the offending class (`IntegerConverter`, in my case).

I had the following Maven dependencies declared (with the RichFaces 4.2.2Final BOM listed earlier):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-ui-validator-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

HOWEVER, the `richfaces-components-ui` is a super-set of `richfaces-ui-validator-ui` (that is, contains it and a few others).

Your configuration / RichFaces components may be different, but the answer lies in what's in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory (whether it got there from Maven or some other way)... you've likely included more than one JAR with a `csv.xml` file.

Identify a minimal set of dependencies and the error will go away.