# Richfaces 4.3.1 weblogic 10.3.5.0 duplicate key on deploy

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, classloader, weblogic11g

I'm having trouble with richfaces 4.3.1 on weblogic 10.3.5.0, on deploy the following exception happens:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! duplicate key: class javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:290)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! duplicate key: class javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:351)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:222)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: class javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:72)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.fromEntryList(ImmutableMap.java:245)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:231)
at org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parseConfig(ClientServiceConfigParser.java:53)
```

I had a look inside ClientServiceConfigParser and debugged it and I found that it ended up loading /META-INF/csv.xml twice from richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar

The method in question is:

```
public static Map<Class<?>, LibraryFunction> parseConfig(String name) {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (null == loader) {
        loader = ClientServiceConfigParser.class.getClassLoader();
    }
    Builder<Class<?>, LibraryFunction> resultBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();
    try {
        Enumeration<URL> resources = loader.getResources(name);
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL url = (URL) resources.nextElement();
            resultBuilder.putAll(parse(loader, url));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    return resultBuilder.build();
}
```

It seems something to do with Weblogic's ChangeAwareClassLoader (`weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader`).  Because inside `org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parseConfig(String)` when it runs `ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();` it ends up returning the `ChangeAwareClassLoader` which happens to get 2 copies of the same resource.  However if I null out the loader (using a debugger) so that it runs `loader = ClientServiceConfigParser.class.getClassLoader();`, then it ends up with a different classloader: `weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader`. Which doesn't get 2 copies of the same resource.

For what it's worth I'm using maven and have loaded in richfaces this way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Before people suggest that I've loaded the wrong maven depdencies, I can tell you its not related to: [IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key (JSF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395965/illegalargumentexception-duplicate-key-jsf)

Because using a debugger I confirmed that `loader.getResources(name);` returns the exact same resource.

```
zip:C:/bea/user_projects/domains/test/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_umsWebUI-jee-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_ear/6m7brt/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar!/META-INF/csv.xml
zip:C:/bea/user_projects/domains/test/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_umsWebUI-jee-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_ear/6m7brt/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar!/META-INF/csv.xml
```

Also for reference I tried the JSF forum and just put a post on the weblogic forums, but I figured I might get a better response here.  The two other posts are here:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2529414
https://community.jboss.org/thread/224100

So aside from compiling my own version of rich faces, does anyone have any ideas of workarounds? How to disable the `ChangeAwareClassLoader` maybe?  My Google searches haven't resulted in anything when trying to disable that class loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get 4.3.1 working in the end.  It turned out that because I was using Skinny Wars in maven, it has unforseen side effects with the ChangeAwareClassLoader. I thought I tried this problem without using Skinny Wars, but I guess I didn't.